# When creating a rails ember app I get :frontend app is not defined, why is this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am trying to create a simple rails ember web app but I am having trouble.

When I run the generate command mentioned below:

```
rails generate ember:init
```

I get this error:

```
lib/ember_cli.rb:21:in `block in app': :frontend app is not defined (KeyError)
```

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_ember_app :frontend, to: "/"
end
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks so much,
Kato.

Comment: hope this will help  https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails/issues/298#issuecomment-159352737

Comment: thanks. It still didn't work though :/

Comment: which version of ember_cli are you using?

Comment: 2.6.1 , should I update to the latest?

Comment: If you can please do it as I see their are lot of things changed... And add the code of config/initializers/ember.rb as well.

Comment: I don't have config/initializers/ember.rb because rails generate ember:init failed